# How to compile Vim 7.3 with +signs on OSX 10.6.6?

Tags: linux, macos, vim, compile

I'm trying to follow this guide http://tech.blog.box.net/2007/06/20/how-to-debug-php-with-vim-and-xdebug-on-linux/ and I need to compile Vim with signs and python options.

I have:

- downloaded the latest source with `hg clone https://vim.googlecode.com/hg/ vim`
- uncommented the signs feature in src/feature.h
- ran `./configure --enable-perlinterp --enable-pythoninterp` with no errors
- ran `make` with this output and errors that I don't understand and can't find on google:

```
$ make
gcc -c -I. -Iproto -DHAVE_CONFIG_H   -DMACOS_X_UNIX -no-cpp-precomp  -g -O2 -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1       -o objects/ex_cmds.o ex_cmds.c
ex_cmds.c: In function ‘ex_sign’:
ex_cmds.c:6736: error: ‘gui’ undeclared (first use in this function)
ex_cmds.c:6736: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
ex_cmds.c:6736: error: for each function it appears in.)
ex_cmds.c:6741: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast
ex_cmds.c: In function ‘sign_gui_started’:
ex_cmds.c:7013: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast
make: *** [objects/ex_cmds.o] Error 1
```

Any daring souls out there that have already been down this path (and/or ones that can tell me where I can move from here) will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [latest comment](http://tech.blog.box.net/2007/06/20/how-to-debug-php-with-vim-and-xdebug-on-linux/comment-page-2/#comment-520) on your referred page,

```
If you get this error:

ex_cmds.c: In function ‘ex_sign’:
ex_cmds.c:6541: error: ‘gui’ undeclared (first use in this function)
ex_cmds.c:6541: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
ex_cmds.c:6541: error: for each function it appears in.)
ex_cmds.c:6546: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast
ex_cmds.c: In function ‘sign_gui_started’:
ex_cmds.c:6832: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast
make[1]: *** [objects/ex_cmds.o] Error 1

The fix for me was to NOT comment out the if statement for:

define FEAT_SIGN_ICONS

So, that define was not set when compiling.
```

Comment: Just like the StackExchange sites here, it is useful to read comments on such posts `:-)`